# AND operation in jsrender

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsrender

Using the AND(&&) operator in JS Render template, throws an exception. But OR(||) operator is working properly.

```
<svg width="100" height="100"  style="margin-top:-50px">
{{if orderValue === 0 && orderValue1 === 1}}
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="orange"></circle>
{{else}}
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="red"></circle>
{{/if}}
</svg>
```

Demo link: https://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/zpv4v5f1

Error details
[image]

Please provide suggestions to resolve this.

Comment: Did my answer below work for you? If so, can you mark it as "accepted"?

Answer (score 2):

You have declared your template inside `<div>` elements. That's not a good idea! You should use script elements.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">...
```

See http://www.jsviews.com/#compiletmpl.

Template markup is not necessarily valid HTML and so putting it in an HTML `<div>` or similar can result in the browser modifying it. In your case the browser is escaping the & symbols: `{{if orderValue === 0 &amp;&amp; orderValue1 === 1}}` - and so it is no longer a valid template.

Also, the version of JsRender you are using is the first beta. There have been many fixes and improvements since then. It would be much better to use a recent version, such as https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jsrender. (See http://www.jsviews.com/#download)

Comment: Your contribution is awesome, +1

Comment: @BorisMoore how would one prevent that escaping in the first place?

Comment: That is standard browser behavior. You can't prevent it, but you don't need to. Use script elements. The  browser does not escape the content of script elements.